Source of quote about the Earth being a living web
Who wrote this:

For the Earth is a Living Web, fragile, subtle, mysteriously linked. Air and water, tree and bird, are shot through with the glory of god. Spirit in matter gives sanctity to life, with humankind the caretaker.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Was this quote originally in English or another language?

Where did you encounter these words? In a book? (If so, which book?) On the Internet? (If so, what URL?)
